# regenerating rspec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

how can I generate rspec on-demand?

the thing was my rspec files were already automatically generated by the "rails generate controller" command. Then I manually deleted those files in hope that there should be a command which I can use to regenerate those files.
What do I do to regenerate those deleted rspec files without firing "rails generate controller" again?

I have tried some command I was suggested by some blog:

```
$ rails generate rspec_controller pages --skip-migration --skip-fixture --skip
Could not find generator rspec_controller.
```

but it didn't work for me.

any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, for two reasons:

- You normally shouldn't be autogenerating your spec files: you need to think about exactly what you want to specify.
- Controller specs should normally not be written at all. Use Cucumber scenarios instead -- they're much less painful and much better at testing *behavior* (controller specs are too dependent on implementation).

Comment: The questioner didn't ask why it's a bad idea. So, regardless of whether or not what they're asking is a bad idea, a more helpful comment would be to answer the question.

Comment: @jackquack If the questioner knew it was a bad idea, he wouldn't be asking how to do it. Since it's a bad idea, I think it's more helpful to the questioner to explain a better way of accomplishing his ultimate goal.

Comment: Well, the asker's question wasn't really answered. And, since most people will probably find this answer with Google, it bad because it just provides another dead-end. But, yes, the asker should be told that it's a bad idea, but bad ideas are opinions. So, I would say that answers should give their opinion, but not without answering the original question.

Comment: @jackquack I kind of disagree with just about all your premises here. Saying "this is bad, but here's how to accomplish the same goal better" isn't a dead end—it's useful technical advice. And I'm not sure I agree that (all) bad ideas are opinions. In software engineering, things are good or bad for demonstrable, factual reasons; thus, ideally, they are not matters of opinion.

Comment: True enough. But, everyone thinks their own opinions are facts, so I like to err on the side of skepticism and always consider my opinions to be possibly flawed.
And even GOTO statements are theoretically a good idea some of the time (though I've never seen it).

Comment: @jackquack One of the nice things about software development is that facts are actually demonstrable, so that relatively few things need to remain matters of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of your app:

```
rails generate controller -h
```

It will show you the usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

`rspec_controller` is deprecated in favour of the standard `controller` generator in Rails. It works now by you including `rspec-rails` within your `Gemfile` like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

This then will load [this file](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec-rails.rb), which customizes what tools the Rails `controller` generator uses with [these two lines](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec-rails.rb#L6-7).